# If $Q$ is orthogonal, $D$ diagonal, $QDQ^T=L^TL$, how to know $L$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $Q$ be an orthogonal matrix made up by the normal eigenvectors of a $n\times n$ nonnegative definite matrix $A$. Let $D=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ be a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of $A$. Then we know that $A=QDQ^T$.

I'm reading "Simultaneous Reduction of a Pair of Quadratic Forms"(Mitra, Rao), and they claim that there exists a matrix $L$ such that $L^TL=A$.

EDIT:
Thanks to the comment of Will Jagy, I know that $L=\sqrt D Q^T$.

Secondly, they claim that $A^{-1}=F^TF,$ and that $F^TL^TLF=I$.

So, $A^{-1}=(QDQ^T)^{-1} = QD^{-1}Q^T$. Then $F=\sqrt{D^{-1}}Q^T.$ And $$F^TL^TLF=Q\sqrt{D^{-1}}Q\sqrt{D}\sqrt D Q^T\sqrt{D^{-1}}Q^T.$$

How is the last expression $I$?? Thanks for your help

Comment: Appears you want $L =  \sqrt D \; Q^T$

Comment: @WillJagy, Thanks, I thought that if I found $L$ I should be able to tackle my ultimate problem which is to show that $F^TL^TLF=I$, but I can't. Can you take a look at this now? I appreciate your help.

Comment: The matrix is not unique. If $X$ is a matrix with $X^TX=Y$ and $O$ is an orthogonal matrix, then for $X'=OX$ we have $X'^TX' = (OX)^TOX = X^TO^TOX = X^TX = Y$. It should be obvious which orthogonal matrix you want to use in the definition of $F$.

Comment: @celtschk Thanks for pointing out that $F$ is not unique. If I take $F=O\sqrt{D^{-1}}Q^T$  So $F^TL^TLF = Q\sqrt{D^{-1}}O^TQDQ^TO\sqrt{D^{-1}}Q^T$, it's not clear to me what $O$ I should take. Can you please post an answer? Thanks.

Comment: @celtschk I just saw that $\sqrt{A^{-1}}A\sqrt{A^{-1}}=I$. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: With $O=Q$, $O^TQ=Q^TQ=I$ and the same for $Q^TO$. Now, $Q\sqrt{D^{-1}}Q^T = \sqrt{A^{-1}}$, so the result is the same solution you've found.